# Profiling with GCC: Get Call Count of Functions in a Shared Library

Tags: c++, gcc, profiling, shared

I would like to be able to count how many times a function is called in a library. I have the C++ source of the library available, but I don't have the source of the executable that uses it.
**Gprof** seams to be a popular tool but it works only for executables. I have found very limited info on sprof, which is supposed to parse profile data gathered during execution, when the library is compiled and linked with the "-g" option. Unfortunately **sprof** is unable to open the resulting profile file. I have pretty much given up trying with **sprof**, since it seams it is something that has been written ages ago and is not up todate.

May question is if you know any tool, that in conjunction with GCC, can calculate the call counts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC, in recent versions, has a compiler switch `-finstrument-functions` which can be used to have it autogenerate tracepoint hooks within compiled code. See [GCC Code Generation Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) in the manual. With that, you don't even need a full-blown interceptor, only a tiny pair of functions:

- `__cyg_profile_func_enter()`
- `__cyg_profile_func_exit()`

that are automatically called at entry/exit to every piece of code compiled with the `-finstrument-functions` option.
You'd simply link a stubs library in that does nothing (just returns) for these, in ordinary use, and another tracer library via `LD_PRELOAD` later if you want to actually record the calls.

Note that the arguments passed to these trace site hooks are addresses of the function being called and the caller; to give names, you'll have to feed them through a symbol table lookup, which is best done *outside* the tracing itself.

Example code (just a quick google, really): [here](http://ndevilla.free.fr/etrace/), [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/184401956), or [here](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/trace-and-profile-function-calls-with-gcc/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily via an LD_PRELOAD library.  You write a library which catches the calls to the function you're instrumenting, increments a counter, and then calls the original implementation (by dlopening the shared object and calling into it).  You then LD_PRELOAD your interceptor library when launching the executable, and have it emit its counts at _exit (or SIGUSR1, or whenever).

This works without any software support beyond a dynamic library loader and is a common technique for indirecting library calls even where the source is not available.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using [ltrace](http://www.ltrace.org/), run your program with `ltrace -c -l yourlibrary`, or drop `-l` to get a count of all dynamic library calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [systemtap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/documentation.html) to get function call count. It is a powerful tool that allows you to instrument at run-time any application without having to recompile it, only debug symbols required.

Here is a script that counts the number of calls to a function along with its execution times in nanoseconds:

```
# call-counts.stp

global calls, times

probe process(@1).function(@2) {
    times[probefunc()] = gettimeofday_ns()
}

probe process(@1).function(@2).return {
    now = gettimeofday_ns()
    delta = now - times[probefunc()]
    calls[probefunc()] <<< delta
}
```

Here is how to use it to count calls to `getenv()` in /lib64/libc-2.12.2.so when running `ls -1`:

```
$ sudo stap -c "ls -1" ~/tmp/count-calls.stp /lib64/libc-2.12.2.so getenv
binned_market_data
count-calls.stp
count-calls.stp~
Makefile
md
nohup.out
calls["getenv"] @count=23 @min=4841 @max=19257 @sum=142529 @avg=6196
```

Another example to see calls to "str*" functions:

```
$ sudo stap -c "ls -1" ~/tmp/count-calls.stp /lib64/libc-2.12.2.so "str*"
binned_market_data
count-calls.stp
count-calls.stp~
Makefile
md
nohup.out
calls["__strdup"] @count=14 @min=5035 @max=10664 @sum=80479 @avg=5748
calls["strcoll"] @count=11 @min=11626 @max=20018 @sum=140851 @avg=12804
calls["__strcoll_l"] @count=11 @min=4992 @max=9393 @sum=63179 @avg=5743
calls["strstr_ifunc"] @count=2 @min=4902 @max=7429 @sum=12331 @avg=6165
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a dynamic library (DLL) you can just recompile it so that it counts and prints out a number that increments whenever the function is called to like a file or over a network